# Где настраиваеться версия протокола HTTP?

Tags: .net, http, веб-сервер, httpclient, webapi

Что необходимо для полноценного внедрения новых версий HTTP?

Для бекенда на Web API это через код нужно делать или через настройку на веб сервере?

Допустим хочу HTTP/3. Есть ли требования для клиентов? Понятно что некоторые браузеры могут не поддерживать его. А для самописных клиентов нужно ли что-то делать и что? Встречал [такой](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28097457/set-http-protocol-version-in-httpclient) вопрос, но не понятно для каких сценариев нужна такая установка.

Comment: Для новых версий HTTP нужно, чтобы его поддержка была реализована в используемых вами веб-сервере и клиенте. Стандартный HttpClient поддерживает [HTTP/2 начиная с .NET Core 3.0](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#http2-support) и [HTTP/3 начиная с .NET 6](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/httpclient-http3) (экспериментально)

Comment: То есть такой клиент будет под капотом отправлять запрос с пометкой HTTP/3 и корректно обрабатывать ответы. А веб сервер(nginx или IIS ) нужно настраивать или нужна только новая версия? Как я понял в коде самого бекенда вообще ничего не нужно писать для этого. Верно?

Comment: Для сервера тоже нужна новая версия, которую нужно настроить согласно документации (поддержку в nginx ещё не сделали, IIS я не использовал, но есть [такая статья](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/networking-blog/enabling-http-3-support-on-windows-server-2022/ba-p/2676880)). Я не знаю, как вы пишите бэкенд, но вроде его код обычно достаточно абстрагирован от специфики HTTP